# Number of solutions to linear system of equations over GF(2)

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

Linear systems of equations over the reals have either 0, 1 or infinitely many solutions. However, when applied to finite fields (specifically GF(2)), infinitely many is not an option.

Is there a fast general method to calculate the *number* of distinct solutions to a linear system of equations over GF(2)?

You can assume that Gaussian elimination has already been performed, so an example augmented matrix would be:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccccccc|c}1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: Is $2^{(\text{number of free variables})}$ not correct? That'd be my naive guess.

Comment: @G.Bach I just realized that you can 'correct' any resulting sum from the free variables using the fixed variables, thus it is indeed $2^f$.

Comment: @Raphael I have already answered my own question - I'm no longer stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take any subset of the free variables, and then correct any resulting sum using the fixed variables.

Thus, after Gaussian elimination the total number of solutions is  $2^f$ where $f$ is the number of free variables.